# Selenium testing two pages at the same time

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

So I have two web pages A and B.
I want to verify that when a change happens at A then that change correctly appears on B.
So what I want to do is launch two Selenium tests at the same time the test testing B then gets to a stage where it needs to wait for the change to happen. So while the test for A is doing its job B waits, and once A is done, it notifies the test running on webpage B to check if the change happened.

Is this possible with Selenium? Or do I need to test web page A first and then open B and check if the change went through?

Comment: dependsonmethods Would be if you need a test to need another method to pass. I'd go with test web page A and make B dependant on that method.

Comment: You can do this by opening a new tab, switching the driver to that tab and then opening page B.  (Same test)

Comment: This can be done in 2 ways.
(1) If your project is using TestNG then used (dependson) attribute. and configure XML to execute test.
(2) Make changes in one tab, then switch to another window and validate the changes.

Comment: @pcalkins is it possible to run them in paralell this way? I mean so both pages open and do there thing. And then have B waits for A to complete?

Comment: Yes.  One thread per driver/browser.  Then notify and all that... seems like it would be a bit complicated though... maintaining which parts are in parallel and which are sequential...  so A would wait until B notifies and waits until A notifies back... etc...

Comment: Might help if you talk in more specific terms here.  If it's to test concurrency, you shouldn't need threads.  What's the use-case?

Comment: @pcalkins well i simply wanted to speed up the test by having the two pages run at the same time. instead of having it in sequence. But yeah that would require the threads to communicate i assume

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `WebDriver` instances. While the first one would be acting on one page, the second one would be monitoring the second page. Below is the simple example:

```java
driver1.get("http://your.domain.test/page1");
driver2.get("http://your.domain.test/page2");
driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//some/xpath")).click();
new FluentWait<>(driver2).until(
        ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(
                        By.xpath("//what/you/expect")
                )
);
```